# "import" methodology using script tags

Tags: javascript

I am trying to import a function coming from a script tag to be used in my code, but I always have errors.

Here's what I tried:

**Test 1**

HTML

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/umd/picmo-popup.js">
import { createPopup } from 'picmo';
console.log("xx")
</script>



<div>
  <button id="test" type="button" class="emoji-button empty"></button>
</div>
```

JS

```
const trigger = document.getElementById("test")

const picker = createPopup({
  // picker options go here
}, {
  referenceElement: trigger,
  triggerElement: trigger
});
```

Error
`"<a class='gotoLine' href='#53:16'>53:16</a> Uncaught ReferenceError: createPopup is not defined"`

**TEST 2**

HTML

```
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/umd/picmo-popup.js">
</script>



<div>
  <button id="test" type="button" class="emoji-button empty"></button>
</div>
```

JS

```
import { createPopup } from 'picmo';

const trigger = document.getElementById("test")

const picker = createPopup({
  // picker options go here
}, {
  referenceElement: trigger,
  triggerElement: trigger
});
```

Error

```
"Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier \&quot;picmo\&quot;. Relative references must start with either \&quot;/\&quot;, \&quot;./\&quot;, or \&quot;../\&quot;."
```

[Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/p6w4bsra/1/)

Any hint?

Comment: If a script tag has `src`, its contents are ignored.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Import" using ESM from CDN throwing errors (Picmo)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73288466/import-using-esm-from-cdn-throwing-errors-picmo)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can load picmo-popup.js directly like that.

But according to [PicMo's documentation](https://picmojs.com/docs/getting-started/installation/#use-esm-from-cdn), you can create a separate file where you can import PicMo and use it:

module.js:

```js
import { createPicker } from 'https://unpkg.com/picmo@latest/dist/index.js';

// More code that does stuff here
```

index.html

```html
<script type="module" src="module.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Lasse, I did manage to make the "PicMo" work using this way but not "picmo-popup.js".
However, I'm not sure what they mean with the second part (index.html) and I won't have access to any page file (index.js/index.html) as it will be added on a no-code tool.
Here's what I tried: [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2s01o9h/) and [Not working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2s01o9h/1/)