# "Import" using ESM from CDN throwing errors (Picmo)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to install the [Popup picker](https://picmojs.com/docs/usage/creating-pickers#popup-picker) from [Picmojs](https://picmojs.com/docs/getting-started/installation) but I am limited by the following:

- I can't modify any file as I am integrating the code in a co-code builder (no access to index.js,..) but can host files
- I can't use NPM nor Yarn as I am working in the browser

**Here's what the documentation says**

> Use ESM from CDN You can also import the ESM version of PicMo
> directly. You will first to create an ES module that imports PicMo:
>
> `index.js import { createPicker } from 'https://unpkg.com/picmo@latest/dist/index.js';`
> `createPicker(...);`
>
> Then you can import the local module from a script tag:
>
> `<script type="module" src="index.js"></script>`

I indeed tried in a Fiddle (even without the script that as I didn't understand this part) and it seems to be working all fine: [Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2s01o9h/)

However, this relates to the `createPicker` function, but I'm interested in the Popup picker and therefore need the `createPopup` function.

**According to their documentation:**

> A popup picker is not displayed until it is triggered by clicking on a
> popup trigger, usually a button.
>
> To use a popup picker, you must first install the @picmo/popup-picker
> package. This package contains the createPopup function.
>
> `createPopup(pickerOptions: PickerOptions, popupOptions: PopupOptions):PopupPickerController`

-> I don't know how to "first install the @picmo/popup-picker package".

Here's what I tried based on the previous working example:

```
import { createPopup } from 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/umd/picmo-popup.js';
```

[Link to Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m2s01o9h/1/)

But I always get the same error: `"<a class='gotoLine' href='#43:10'>43:10</a> Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/umd/picmo-popup.js' does not provide an export named 'createPopup'"`

Any hint for me? I'm really stuck on this part.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use the UMD version of the library, but you can't use UMD with ESM.

Based on your URL, I tried `https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@5.4.0/dist/index.js` which gave me this error:

> TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "picmo". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

That tells us that the file uses `import ____ from "picmo"`, which won't work in the browser without an [import map](https://wicg.github.io/import-maps/). If your target browsers [support them](https://caniuse.com/import-maps), we can do that like this:

```html
<script type="importmap">
{
    "imports": {
        "picmo": "https://unpkg.com/picmo@5.4.2/dist/index.js",
        "@picmo/popup-picker": "https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@5.4.0/dist/index.js"
    }
}
</script>
<script type="module">
import { createPopup } from "@picmo/popup-picker";
console.log(typeof createPopup);
</script>
```

...but sadly as I write this import maps are just supported by Chromium-based browsers like Chrome, Edge, and Opera, not Firefox or Safari.

If you need to target those as well, the `import ____ from "picmo"` would *seem* like an insurmountable barrier, but unpkg.com has a feature to "expand" bare `import`s. From the unpkg home page:

> **Query Parameters**
>
> `?meta`
>
> Return metadata about any file in a package as JSON (e.g. `/any/file?meta`)
>
> `?module`
>
> Expands all [“bare” import specifiers](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#resolve-a-module-specifier) in JavaScript modules to unpkg URLs. This feature is *very experimental*

And indeed, adding `?module` to that URL to ask unpkg to do that for us works:

```html
<script type="module">
import { createPopup } from "https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@5.4.0/dist/index.js?module";
console.log(typeof createPopup);
</script>
```

Since that imports picmo, you'll want to watch the network tab to see what exact URL is used to import picmo and use that if you need to import it in your code (so you're getting the same instance). For instance, when I did that just now it requested `https://unpkg.com/picmo@%5E5.0.1?module` and got a redirect pointing to `https://unpkg.com/picmo@5.4.2?module` which also returned a redirect pointing to `https://unpkg.com/picmo@5.4.2/dist/index.js?module`. That would suggest you want to import picmo from `https://unpkg.com/picmo@%5E5.0.1?module` (the first URL, since that's what the JavaScript engine will have seen), but you'll need to experiment to be sure.

---

**All of that aside**, it's well worth dropping them a note asking whether this is really how you should do it and/or asking for a way that doesn't rely on a "very experimental" feature of unpkg.com.

Comment: Wahoo, that's a really complete answer, I can't thank you enough for that!
I managed to make it work using your solution, but it only works in Fiddle for some reason and throws the `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module` error when used on a regular web page.
I made a  [new post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73309614/pure-js-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module) to add more details @T.J. Crowder

Comment: @vnihoul - That just means you're trying to use `import` in code you haven't loaded with `type="module"` on the `script` tag.

Answer (score -1):

(Source @joeattardi from Github)

You're using the UMD version of the module with an `import` statement. This won't work; only ES modules work with `imports`. UMD modules are loaded with a `script` tag.

But then you are mixing an ESM import (your import of the main picmo package) with a UMD, which won't work either.

Two options:

1. Use the UMD version of the base picmo package as well, both loaded with `script` tags.
2. Use the ESM distribution of @picmo/popup-picker from unpkg. Note that you will need to add `?module` to the URL, otherwise your browser will likely give an error about an invalid relative path. If you do it this way you don't need the picmo import since the popup module imports it.

So for the ESM route, you need just a single import:

```
import { createPopup } from 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/index.js?module';
```