# Use a function from an import statement in a script module tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the `createPopup` function that I imported using the `import` function in my script tag.

However, I always get the error stating the function is not defined (`Uncaught ReferenceError: createPopup is not defined"`)

Here's my code from [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zwtyqdgr/1/):

HTML

```
<script type="module">
import { createPopup } from 'https://unpkg.com/@picmo/popup-picker@latest/dist/index.js?module';
</script>
```

JS

```
const triggerButton = document.getElementById('button');

// Create the picker
const picker = createPopup()
```

Any hint on how to import it properly? Because it works fine [this way](http://jsfiddle.net/o1086prb/).

> Note: I need to use the `import` function and I can't just add the library as my script tag source as I am using the `?module` parameter from Unpkg. I a using pure JS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: *Because it works fine this way.* so why don't you use it that way?

Comment: This happens because the module is not loaded in the same context as your JS file. Just remember that `import` creates a "sealed off" context that can only be reached by code in the same context.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure JS - SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73318536/pure-js-syntaxerror-cannot-use-import-statement-outside-a-module)

Comment: @Liam The main goal is to integrate this code on a no-code app builder and use the variables provided by their editor as parameters from my createPopup function. Unfortunately, these variables will be inaccessible if I add my entire code inside the script tag. Also, I would like to be able to load the module first and then call the function later.

Comment: @Kokodoko, am I able to add my imported function in a variable and somehow make it available to the rest of the code? As in if I was importing a library inside the script tag source?

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over. You've [already had this question answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73288847/542251)

Comment: If you want to make an `imported` function global you could do something like `import { bla } from "file.js"` followed by `window.bla = bla`. This places `bla` on the global window object which can be reached from anywhere. This is a bit of an anti-pattern though :)

Comment: This would be absolutely perfect as I would just need to store my function inside this global variable. However, trying to implement your solution always returns an undefined function [like on this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6k1qjLce/) @Kokodoko

Comment: That's because you have to wait until the module has loaded, see the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to make variables or functions from an `imported` module globally available you can place them on the global window scope.

**After the module has loaded**, those variables or functions will be available on `window` in other scripts. You can use `defer` to wait for the first module to load.

MYMODULE.JS

```
console.log('part 1');
export const test = 'hello there';
```

SCRIPT.JS

```
console.log('part 2');
console.log(window.test);
```

INDEX.HTML

```
<script id="myscript" type="module">
  import { test } from './mymodule.js';
  console.log('imported: ' + test);
  window.test = test;
</script>
<script defer src="script.js"></script>
```

See this stackblitz : https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-mvedtp?file=index.html

Just be aware that this is an anti-pattern, it's much better to just `import` the module directly in the script where you need it.